# How atomic update is implemented in Coroutines

Tags: atomic, kotlin-coroutines

Here's update function from Coroutines StateFlow. I have two questions:

1. How is it atomic? We have multiple operations inside, how can atomicity be guaranteed without mutual exclusion?
2. Why is it in while(true) loop? At what condition the loop is necessary?
3. Can the loop be endless?

```kotlin
/**
 * Updates the [MutableStateFlow.value] atomically using the specified [function] of its value.
 *
 * [function] may be evaluated multiple times, if [value] is being concurrently updated.
 */
public inline fun <T> MutableStateFlow<T>.update(function: (T) -> T) {
    while (true) {
        val prevValue = value
        val nextValue = function(prevValue)
        if (compareAndSet(prevValue, nextValue)) {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not specific to coroutines. Locking/critical sections is only one way to achieve synchronization. CAS operations are another one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap . In many cases CAS is much faster than locking.

Comment: @broot I do agree that it is not specific to coroutines. Thou the questions are still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `update` operation itself isn't atomic, there are multiple operations within it. However, the part where it actually swaps out the out-of-date state for the new state: `compareAndSet(prevValue, nextValue)` is atomic.
2. This is the clever part: it uses CAS (Compare And Set) technique - different to the method call I was talking about - whereby we copy the old value into `prevValue` and then what the new value should be by running the lambda, `function` on `prevValue`. This gives us the `nextValue`. Now, we need to remember that we must be running thread-safe code, so the `prevValue` might have changed while we were running the function, for this reason, `compareAndSet(prevValue, nextValue)` does the following (from the Kotlin reference): "Atomically compares the current value with expect and sets it to update if it is equal to expect. The result is true if the value was set to update and false otherwise.". So, what this means is that if `prevValue` is out of date with the current value (this means that another thread has updated the current value while we were running the function) then we should repeat the whole loop again, otherwise we return. This method guarantees thread safety, we will never overwrite changes from another thread and vice versa!
3. Yes, as with all loops in a `while(true)` with a conditioned break, this loop will run indefinitely, until `compareAndSet` returns `true`. Just as an aside to this, something I learned the other day: Kotlin coroutines inherit [`isActive`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/is-active.html), you can use this to create a compliant coroutine that can cancel when the scope is shut down by doing `while(isActive)`. Rarely is `while(true)` a good idea :)